# Suppose $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is integrable function. Show that $\liminf_{j\to \infty} \int_{j}^{j+1} |f|=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Suppose $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is integrable function. Show that $$\liminf_{j\to \infty} \int_{j}^{j+1} |f|=0.$$

Seeing the $\liminf $ here I tought that I could use Fatou's lemma, but doesn't seem like it since I would only get a lower bound for the integral which I'm not looking for. From $\liminf$ I have few properties, seems like $\int_{j}^{j+1} |f|$ is the "sequence" here for $\liminf$ and so I would have $$\liminf_{j\to \infty} \int_{j}^{j+1} |f| -\varepsilon\le \int_{j}^{j+1} |f|$$ for $n \ge N \in \Bbb N$. Also $$\liminf_{j\to \infty} \int_{j}^{j+1} |f| \le \limsup_{j\to \infty} \int_{j}^{j+1} |f|.$$

Neither one of these doesn't really seem to help. Is there some other properties I should know of to use here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|=\int_{(-\infty,0]}|f|+\sum^\infty_{j=0}\int_{(j,j+1]}|f|$$
Since by assumption $f\in L_1$, $\int|f|<\infty$ and the series $\sum_j\int_{(j,j+1]}|f|<\infty$.

Comment: So you’re breaking the integral of $f$ over whole $\Bbb R$ to parts from $(-\infty, 0)$ and then summing the integral of the bits $(j, j+1]$?

Comment: @JimingLe: $(-\infty,0]$ and then by integer intervals $(j,j+1]$ of length $1$. The assumption of integrability implies that the series (with nonnegative terms) $\sum^\infty_{j=0}\int_{(j,j+1]}|f|$ is convergent and so, $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\int_{(j,j+1]}|f|=0$ (not only $\liminf_j$).

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach (by contradiction)**
Suppose for the sake of contradiction that
$$\tag{*}\liminf_{j\to \infty}\int_{j}^{j+1}|f|\geq \alpha >0. $$

Then by $(*)$ there exists an increasing sequence of indices $(j_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $|j_{n+1}-j_n|\geq 1$ (why?)
$$\tag{**}\int_{j_n}^{j_n+1}|f|\geq \frac{\alpha}{2}>0,$$
for all $n$. Then for every $N$ we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_{j_n}^{j_n+1}|f|\,\geq\sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_{j_n}^{j_n+1}\frac{\alpha}{2}=N\cdot \frac{\alpha}{2}.$$
Therefore, for every $N\geq 1$ we have that
$$\int|f|\,\geq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\int_{j_n}^{j_n+1}|f|\,\geq N\cdot \frac{\alpha}{2}.$$
Letting $N\to \infty$ we conclude that $\int|f|=\infty$ and we derive the contradiction, hence
$$\liminf_{j\to\infty}\int_{j}^{j+1}|f|\,=0.$$